Custom Table Creation
I want to create a table which looks like the one in the picture, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Is there anyone who can help me with it?

\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
 \usepackage{array}                                  
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{tabularray}
 \usepackage{hhline}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
 \usepackage{float}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \caption{}
 \begin{tabular}{|M{2.5cm}|c|c||M{2.5cm}|c|c|}\hline
      &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hhline{|=|=|=||=|=|=|}
      &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
      &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
      &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
      &  &   \\ \hline
      &  &  \\ \hline
      &  &   \\ \hline\hline
      &  &  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \label{tab:}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}

This is what i have now

What's the concrete problem? What have you tried so far? Do you know at least basic tabular line commands like \hline and \cline and other basic table features of TeX? If not, please read a tutorial. Note also, there are already lots of examples for tables. Just click to the [tag:tables] tag. And are you sure, this is a table and not a kind of matrix (→ [tag:tikz-matrix]) or image? And what is the [tag:overleaf] relation of this question? Just using Overleaf is not enough to set the tag. You should use the tag only, if using overleaf is relevant for the question.

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|M{2.5cm}|c|c||M{2.5cm}|c|c|}\hline
&  &  &  &  &   \ \hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|=|}
&  &  &  &  &   \ \hline
&  &  &  &  &   \ \hline
&  &  &  &  &   \ \hline
&  &   \ \hline
&  &  \ \hline
Text &  &   \ \hline\hline
Text &  &  \ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:OnderdelenHerontwerpKaak}
\end{table}
The problem is that thee 2 lines with 'text'should be on the right side next to the third line from the bottom. I've tried multicolumn

Please add all relevant information to the question. Comments are not suitable this. And please read: I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?

Off-topic: You don't need to use table for tables and it does not really make sense to use table if you don't use a \caption{…}.

I do use a caption, its just not filled in...

Once again: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. See also the MWE link in my previous comment.

Is it better now?

Your example still does not compile (even if I add \documentclass{article}). Please try it. And you are loading packages, which are not used in the example. Nevertheless, tabularray could be useful. Have you read the manual? Should there be content in the table or should it stay empty? If there should be content, are the vertical larger cells one row or several rows? Sorry, but your question is still not clear. And still you've not told where concrete you failed and need help.

Yes, the rows should be continuous so they should go through the double vertical line. There should be content inside of the table, but I don't think that's relevant now. And my question is basically how to make the table shown in the picture

What is in the post compiles for me now

Is the table filled with data, or do you just need the skeleton in the picture? Data tables usually don't need so many rules, especially the vertical ones. If the table has data, can you please add an example?

Does something like this work for you:
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|c|c||p{2.5cm}|c|c|}\hline
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC  \\ \hline
        &     &     &     &     &      \\[-2.2ex] \hline
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC  \\ \hline
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC  \\ \hline
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC  \\ \cline{4-6}
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC \\ \hline
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC\\ \cline{4-6}
  ABC   & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC & ABC \\ \hline\hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c||}{ABC}   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ABC} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

Since I don't know what content you'd like to have in your cells, I've been guessing a little.

Yes, this seems to be working. Thanks a lot. The only minor detail which isn't necessary to change is that because I use some pictures inside the table, the horizontal line which is only spans the last 3 columns does not divide the cells of the 5th and 6th row equally. But again this is just a small detail and doesn't necessarily need to be changed, thanks a lot!

You say, whether there is content and what kind of content is not relevant for the question. Here an example, how to print lines like in the image of your question as a table:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \setlength{\unitlength}{.005\linewidth}%
  \caption{}
  \begin{picture}(183,320)(0,-12)
    \linethickness{2pt}%
    \multiput(0,20)(30,0){4}{\line(0,1){280}}
    \multiput(93,20)(30,0){4}{\line(0,1){280}}
    \put(0,0){\line(1,0){183}}
    \put(0,15){\line(1,0){183}}
    \put(0,0){\line(0,1){15}}
    \put(90,0){\line(0,1){15}}
    \put(93,0){\line(0,1){15}}
    \put(183,0){\line(0,1){15}}
    \put(0,20){\line(1,0){183}}
    \put(0,280){\line(1,0){183}}
    \put(0,283){\line(1,0){183}}
    \put(0,300){\line(1,0){183}}
    \put(93,53){\line(1,0){90}}
    \multiput(0,85)(0,65){3}{\line(1,0){90}}
    \multiput(93,85)(0,65){3}{\line(1,0){90}}
  \end{picture}
\end{table}
\end{document}


